# spark.table() name for use in join

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df1 = (spark.table('tab1')
                        .where(
                                (F.col("yyyy") == year)
                              )
                     )
df2 = df1.join(df_old, df1.uid==df_old.fid, "inner")
```

how can I so the same code like this?

```
df1 = (spark.table('tab1')
                        .where(
                                (F.col("yyyy") == year)
                              )
                     ).join(df_old, ???? ==df_old.fid, "inner")
```

How mention a df created with spark.table()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **.alias()** for this case in join and refer the `alias name` in your join `on` condition.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',1,2),('b',2,4),('c',3,5)],['i','j','k'])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('a',1,2),('c',3,5)],['i1','j2','k3'])
df.where(col("i")!="c").alias("a").join(df1.alias("b"),col("a.i")==col("b.i1")).show(10,False)
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|i  |j  |k  |i1 |j2 |k3 |
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|a  |1  |2  |a  |1  |2  |
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: was asking how to refer the table (tab1) not column

Comment: with `.alias()` you can refer to the `tab1` with where clause filter in it..

Answer (score 0):

Not just column but dataframe can can also be aliased. as mentioned [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-alias-column-examples/?expand_article=1#:%7E:text=3.%20Alias%20DataFrame%20Name)

eg: `df.alias('df_one')`

So the answer is

```
df1 = (spark.table('tab1')
                        .where(
                                (F.col("yyyy") == year)
                              ).alias("df_tab1")
                     ).join(df_old, F.col("df_tab1.uid") ==df_old.fid, "inner")
```